# how to use if statement with onclick to alert for multiple divs

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to display an onclick alert if the correct circle has been clicked plus I want the color of the circle to be changed if the correct one clicked... sorry I'm new at programming and I really hope anyone would help me out here, appreciate the help.

P.S The "else" condition is working instead of the "if"

the code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("redCircle").onclick = function() {
        var circleClicked = document.getElementById("redCircle").onclick;
        if(circleClicked == redCircle) {
            document.getElementById("redCircle").style.background = "red";
            alert("You got it right");
        } else {
            alert("Sorry, try again");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What do you expect the `if (...)` to do? You're comparing whatever is stored in `onclick` (most likely a function) with `redCircle` (which is most likely the element with the id `redCircle`). This will never work...

Comment: Thanks @Andreas, the explanation helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two reasons why you're code is not working:

1. `redCircle` in your if condition is not declared as a variable. Javascript doesn't know what redCircle is.
2. You can't declare a variable `circleClicked` with an event listener. You attach an event listener to a variable.

Is this what you're looking for? I'm posting with `onclick` as well as `addEventListener` . But I would suggest you to use the latter.

```js
const circles = document.querySelectorAll('.circles');

circles.forEach(el => {
    el.onclick = function(e) {
        if(e.target.id === 'correctCircle'){
            e.target.style.background = 'red';
            alert("You got it right");
        }else{
            alert("Sorry, try again");
        }
    };
});
```

```css
.circles {
  width:50px; 
  height:50px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  background-color: green; 
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="circles" id="correctCircle"></div>
<div class="circles"></div>
```

Using `addEventListener`:

```js
const circles = document.querySelectorAll('.circles');

circles.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if(e.target.id === 'correctCircle'){
        e.target.style.background = 'red';
        alert("You got it right");
    }else{
        alert("Sorry, try again");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.circles {
  width:50px; 
  height:50px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  background-color: green; 
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="circles" id="correctCircle"></div>
<div class="circles"></div>
```

So basically what I did here is declaring a variable called `circles` and then looping through each one of them to check if any one of them has an id of `correctCircle`.

Event Listeners has a parameter which we called `e` that has information about everything that event is attached to. And `e.target` gives you the div just clicked on. For example, if you clicked on the first circle, then `e.target` will give you the div of that circle only. So therefore if that div has an id of `correctCircle` then it changes the background color and alerts you.

Hope it helps.

Comment: wow, great help sir @Zak, really appreciate it.

Comment: @xangetsue  Hope I could help. Can you please choose the answer if it is what you're looking for?